# how to get query params inside getInitialProps?

Tags: next.js, routes, query-string

Here is my code I want to update the meta content based on the query parameter.
For Example localhost:3000/in
I need to fetch the meta content for India and need to update on .
But I can't fetch the query parameters on getInitialProps. how to get query params inside getInitialProps?

```
function StartApp({ Component, pageProps, initialAsideLeftHandler }) {
  return <>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Head>
        <title>{initialAsideLeftHandler[2].values}</title>
        <meta name="title" content={initialAsideLeftHandler[2].values} />
        <meta name="description" content={initialAsideLeftHandler[1].values} />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Header/>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Footer />
    </Provider>
  </>
}

StartApp.getInitialProps =  async ({query}) => {
  
  let parameter = {
    "countryCode": "in",
    "slug": "home",
  }
  let data =  await getMetaContent(parameter);
   
  return { initialAsideLeftHandler: data } 
}
```

Comment: Is `StartApp` a page component in `pages` folder?

Comment: Yes, StartApp is a main function from _app.js